# Proguard Error for External Libraries

Tags: android, proguard

I was getting these errors for proguard with some external libraries.

1. can't find referenced class
2. can't find superclass or interface

Now after adding -**dontwarn** for these jars, it finishes the build process successfully but at **runtime** my app is not working properly. I am getting **javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException** when I'm logging in through my app. This works perfectly fine without proguard obfuscation.

**Here is my code for proguard.cfg**

```
-injars bin/classes
-outjars bin/classes-processed.jar

-libraryjars usr/local/android-15/android.jar
-libraryjars /libs/bugsense-1.9.jar
-libraryjars /libs/Facebook.jar
-libraryjars /libs/FlurryAgent.jar
-libraryjars /libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-5.0.0.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jackson-core-asl-1.7.4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar
-libraryjars /libs/asmack-android-5.jar
-libraryjars /libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar

-dontpreverify
-allowaccessmodification
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-repackageclasses ''

-dontwarn com.inmobi.androidsdk.**
-dontwarn com.mobclix.android.sdk.**
-dontwarn com.millennialmedia.android.**
-dontwarn com.jumptap.adtag.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.mobclix.android.sdk.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.os.AsyncTask
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public interface com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

De-Obfuscated Logcat Report

```
    11-10 00:51:39.893: W/System.err(1631): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
    11-10 00:51:39.893: W/System.err(1631):     at 11-14 21:18:44.491: W/System.err(13184): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:258)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.void verify(java.lang.String,javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                       void verify(java.lang.String,java.security.cert.X509Certificate)
                                                                                       void verify(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[],boolean)
                                                                                       boolean acceptableCountryWildcard(java.lang.String)
                                                                                       java.lang.String[] getCNs(java.security.cert.X509Certificate)
                                                                                       java.lang.String[] getSubjectAlts(java.security.cert.X509Certificate,java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[] createKeyManagers(java.security.KeyStore,java.lang.String)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                       javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[] createTrustManagers(java.security.KeyStore)
                                                                                       java.net.Socket createSocket()
                                                                                       java.net.Socket connectSocket(java.net.Socket,java.lang.String,int,java.net.InetAddress,int,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                       boolean isSecure(java.net.Socket)
                                                                                       java.net.Socket createSocket(java.net.Socket,java.lang.String,int,boolean)
                                                                                       void setHostnameVerifier(org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection createConnection()(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                       void openConnection(org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection,org.apache.http.HttpHost,java.net.InetAddress,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                                       void updateSecureConnection(org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection,org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                                       void prepareSocket(java.net.Socket,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.java.lang.Object getState()(Unknown Source)
                                                                                         void setState(java.lang.Object)
                                                                                         void open(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                         void tunnelTarget(boolean,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                         void tunnelProxy(org.apache.http.HttpHost,boolean,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                         void layerProtocol(org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.void open(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                 void tunnelTarget(boolean,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                                 void tunnelProxy(org.apache.http.HttpHost,boolean,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                                 void layerProtocol(org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext,org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
                                                                                                 void setState(java.lang.Object)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper wrapRequest(org.apache.http.HttpRequest)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                void rewriteRequestURI(org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper,org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute)
                                                                                                org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                                void releaseConnection()
                                                                                                void establishRoute(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                                boolean createTunnelToProxy(org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute,int,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                                org.apache.http.impl.client.RoutedRequest handleResponse(org.apache.http.impl.client.RoutedRequest,org.apache.http.HttpResponse,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                                void processChallenges(java.util.Map,org.apache.http.auth.AuthState,org.apache.http.client.AuthenticationHandler,org.apache.http.HttpResponse,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                                void updateAuthState(org.apache.http.auth.AuthState,org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest)
                                                                                            org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler)
                                                                                            java.lang.Object execute(org.apache.http.HttpHost,org.apache.http.HttpRequest,org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler,org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.services.secure.HttpsWebServiceHelper.java.lang.String doPost(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map,java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.services.secure.HttpsWebServiceHelper.java.lang.String doPost(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map,java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.activity.LoginActivity$LoginAsyncTask.java.lang.String doInBackground(java.lang.Void[])(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        void onPostExecute(java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.activity.LoginActivity$LoginAsyncTask.java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.Object[])(Unknown Source)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-14 21:18:44.501: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184): java.io.IOException
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.services.secure.HttpsWebServiceHelper.java.lang.String doPost(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map,java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.services.secure.HttpsWebServiceHelper.java.lang.String doPost(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost)(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
                                                                                                        java.lang.String doPost(java.lang.String,java.util.Map,java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.activity.LoginActivity$LoginAsyncTask.java.lang.String doInBackground(java.lang.Void[])(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                        void onPostExecute(java.lang.String)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at com.mypackage.android.activity.LoginActivity$LoginAsyncTask.java.lang.Object doInBackground(java.lang.Object[])(Unknown Source)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-14 21:18:44.511: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-14 21:18:44.521: W/System.err(13184):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-14 21:18:44.521: W/System.err(13184):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
```

Comment: Post the logcat of the APP crash..

Comment: Those mentioned with **-libraryjars** in the code.

Comment: Please post the manifest too.

Comment: I have done some changes & now I'm getting a different output. Please check the post

Comment: I got a similar warning in proguard output (and a runtime crash on class not found after adding a -dontwarn) after I started using "-useuniqueclassmembernames".  It might be worth trying a compile without that flag.